# Get the name of an element of a Page Object

Tags: page-object-gem

Is it possible to get the identifier of a PageObject Element by having only the Element? (The cheezy pageobject gem)

Is there any attribute of the Element that keeps the name of the element.

For instance, in this case:

```
text_field(:name, :id => 'name')
```

if I have only the element, how can I find its name out? :)

Thanks for the help.

---

Edit:

Ok, so here's what I am trying to do:

I have a pageObject called AttributePage, which has some elements defined:

```
class AttributePage < PropertyPage
  include PageObject
  include DataMagic

  page_url NavigationHelpers::get_path 'catalog-attributes'


  # Header
  textfield(:attribute_sets, :id =>'ext-1') # 1.
  textfield(:global_attributes, :id => 'ext-2') # 2.

end
```

and a PageObject PropertyPage that looks like this:

```
class PropertyPage
  include PageObject

  def get_search_filter_elements
    element_methods = self.class.instance_methods(false).find_all{ |m| m =~ /_element$/ }
    elements = element_methods.collect{ |m| self.send(m) }
    return_array =[]
    for x in 0...element_methods.size
      return_array.append([element_methods[x].to_s.gsub('_element', ''), elements[x]])
    end
    return return_array
  end
```

This way, when I call

```
on_page(AttributePage).get_search_filter_elements
```

I get a list of PageObject::Element.
What I wanted to do was to call the AttributePage.fill_elements that would look like this:

```
def fill_elements
  elements = get_search_filter_elements
  elements.each do |element|
     # Now this doesn't work
     element.text = read_from_some_file_for_element_name element.name
  end
```

is there any way I can do this?

Comment: `name` means what ? Are you talking about `tag`.. Not clear ..

Comment: Your question is mixing unrelated components here.
"Element" in the generic sense always refers an element in your html. Element Object in the PO gem is a generic wrapper for 'WatirWebDriver::Element' or 'SeleniumWebDriver::Element'

You need to clarify this.

It seems as though you might be referring to the PageObject::Element, then what are you asking? What is it's method name in this example you have provided?
Answer: The symbol name you provided as arg[0]: ':name' in text_field(). To access it, you would call name_element() within the context of your page object.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jared.
What I'm looking for is the "name", the id of the PO element. I have  access only to the Element Object. And having only the Selenium::Webdriver::Element, how can I do that? Is there an "element.name" method or something like that? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the `get_search_filter_elements` method already returning the name, but the `fill_elements` method is using the returned result incorrectly?

Comment: I would submit that this is the hard way and a bit of wheel reinvention is going on with your approach, but that isn't your question. The answer(s) are where @JustinKo just stated and in my answer below.

Comment: @Jared_Casey, yes, that was the way I found out to solve this: I returned a hash with the name and the element so I could use it. Before asking the question, I was only returning the element and I couldn't find the "name" I gave to it in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me first create a more complete page object (PO) class for reference

Assuming you have some html on a page with a text field that has an id of 'name'

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="zzz" name="yyy"/>

class MyPage
    include PageObject
    text_field(:name, :id => 'name')
end

myPage = MyPage.new
p myPage.name_element #Output => PageObject::Elements::TextArea
p myPage.name?        #Output => 'true'
p myPage.name         #Output => 'zzz'
myPage.name = 'bbb' #Sets value of text_field to 'bbb'
p myPage.name         #Output => 'bbb'
```

These four methods are all dynamically created as a result of defining the page element 'text_field(:name, ...)'

Your question is ambiguous, but I think what you are wanting to know is, now that you have this element mapped in the page object, how would you go about getting it's name, meaning it's html name? Well that will only work if the html element in question has a 'name' attribute. If it does, like my example above, then you would access it's name using the name_element object, like so:

```
p myPage.name_element.name #Output => 'yyy'
```

Comment: I already edited the question so you can understand it better :)